# Application logging architecture

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nlog

I'm writing an ASP .NET MVC3 application and as application is expected to be secure, I need a good enterprise application logging architecture.

So I was seeking over existing loggin frameworks and picked the [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/). So at them moment I'm stuck with making DB schema for logs.

Does anyone have good experience in this area? It's anticipate to log a set of actions such as user interactions with system objects, background works, user membership actions, payment transactions and so on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've been using NLog for a while now and i'm very happy with it. What I most like about NLog is that you can configure different loglevels to be written to different files and/or databases. It's a very powerfull logging library.

For logging to the database you can use something like below in your config. This is similar to what I use at the company i'm working.

```
<target xsi:type="Database" 
        name="TestDatabaseLogging" 
        connectionString="Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=NLog_Test;User ID=MyLogin;Password=MyPassword" 
        dbDatabase="NLog_Test">
  <commandText>
    insert into INNO_LOG ([createDate], [Origin], [LogLevel], [Message], [Exception], [StackTrace]) values (@createDate, @origin, @logLevel, @message, @exception, @stackTrace)
  </commandText>
  <parameter name="@createDate" layout="${date}"/>
  <parameter name="@origin" layout="${callsite}"/>
  <parameter name="@logLevel" layout="${level}"/>
  <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}"/>
  <parameter name="@exception" layout="${exception:format=Message,StackTrace}"/>
  <parameter name="@stackTrace" layout="${stacktrace}"/>
</target>
```

You can use the rules section to log different levels to different files, see example below;

```
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Fatal" writeTo="mail" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="TestDatabaseLogging" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file-debug" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="file" />
    <!--Log to specific files for specific classes.-->
    <logger name="_Default" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file-default" />
    <logger name="TestClass" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file-testclass" />
  </rules>
```

EDIT: Added possible table layout for logging information.

```
Id | int
CreateDate | datetime
LogLevel | nvarchar
Message | nvarchar(max)
Exception | nvarchar(max)
StackTrace | nvarchar(max)
SourceUrl | nvarchar(255)
UserId | uniqueidentifier
OrderId | int
```

The layout above is just an rough idea. It totally depends on what you want to log in this table. Though you have to try if it's possible to add additional paramaters other than the ones used by NLog by default.

Comment: Your way is like to deal with exception situations (e.g. impossible to connect to DB at all or something like that). But what can I do with situations like 'user is successfully logged in'?

Comment: I would use the info level for that. You can then do something like _logger.info("user: *** successfully logged in.").  In the config you can determine to log the info to the database or file. Personally I always assume something works, so I never log that. I only log the exceptual situation, like when an error occurs or an user tries to login in with the wrong password to often.

Comment: Why do you want to log info like 'user is successfully logged in'?

Comment: I think it's better to log than don't log :) It may be useful to learn about user typical behaviot, what make the system better in future, for instance.

Comment: If you ask me, knowing that a user logged in isn't learning about their behavior. Why not track this with google analytics? Else if not possible I would log this in a seperate table so you can get an overview from these actions later on.

Comment: So that table you mention 'I would log this in a seperate table so you can get an overview from these actions later on' is what I'm asking you. What is most appropriate table design for logging as much information as possible?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! What is the `OrderId`? Is it better to use some `EventId` instead of `Message`? So, you can suggest what `EventId = 1` means _User has successfully logged on_.

Comment: You're welcome. OrderId is just an optional field since I don't know your architecture and the fields you want to save. You can add columns as much as you like, as long as they match your insert query in your config. And i'm not sure if you can insert values, other then the defaults. EventId = 1 could be i guess. Might also be an option to match eventid's to an enum somehow (if possible)

Comment: NLog is the right way to go. We combine it with Splunk for some pretty powerful information retrieval.

Answer (score 7):

Like Rob has answered .. stick with NLog :)

If you need a good viewer, don't forget to use [Sentinal](http://sentinel.codeplex.com/) as a free nLog viewer :)

Don't forget, you can programatically turn on logging sections, while in production .. to view specific areas of the website. And then see them in real-time using Sentinal.

[image]

---

another option is to take advanctage of something like [LoggR.net](http://loggr.net/). This streams data (ie. errors or logging information in this case) in real time. I think it's using the awesome [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) framework to use WebSockets or Long Polling (2 real-time technologies) :)

[image]